Swiper autoplay.start() not resuming instantly
I have a carousel that continuously keeps showing different client logo's.
There is a pause button that instantly pauses the carousel.
When that pause button is clicked again the carousel should play again starting from the point where it stopped.
And it does, but not without a random delay.
Here is the Codepen => https://codepen.io/grasmachien/pen/JoPYxNb?editors=1010
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
  slidesPerView: 2,
  spaceBetween: 40,
  speed: 4000,
  effect: "slide",
  loop: true,
  freeMode: true,
  preventInteractionOnTransition: true,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 0,
    pauseOnMouseEnter: false,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
    waitForTransition: true,
    stopOnLastSlide: false,
    running: true,
  },
  breakpoints: {
    650: {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 40,
      speed: 4000,
    },
    1000: {
      slidesPerView: 4,
      spaceBetween: 60,
    },
    1200: {
      slidesPerView: 5,
      speed: 5000,
      spaceBetween: 80,
    },
  },
});

document.querySelector('.btn-pause').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (swiper.autoplay.running) {
        swiper.setTranslate(swiper.getTranslate());
        swiper.autoplay.stop();
    } else {
        swiper.slideTo(swiper.activeIndex, 3000, false);
        swiper.autoplay.start();
    }
});

Does anyone know what is going on here?
It seems like a weird bug.
